# How to print in excel with iteration per column based on value (number)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to achieve something that increments per column based on the value given.
Like,

```
if A1 = "ABC" and B1 = 3 then C1 = "ABC", D1 = "ABC" and E1 = "ABC".
If A1 = "ABC" and B1 = 1 then C1 = "ABC"
If A1 = "ABC" and B1 = 2 then C1 = "ABC" and D1 = "ABC"
```

I haven't tried anything yet, I only have the logic.

I have seen some codes but it's VB, what i was trying to achieve was using formula.

Expected output is what above describes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Excel***

In cell `C1`:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A1)<=$B1,$A1,"")
```

Drag right till the max you think you must go based on `B1`

[image]

***Google Spreadsheets***

In cell `C1`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((COLUMN(C1:KN1)-2)<=B1,A1,""))
```

Change `KN1` to whichever column would be the max and enter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in one go with Google sheets:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(column(C1:indirect(address(counta(A:A),max(B:B)+2)))>B:B+2,"",A:A))
```

[image]

There's also

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A:A="","",split(rept(A:A&"|",B:B),"|")))
```

but this is limited to 50K characters per row.